# How can I specify different ansible_password for each host in my playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

In inventory file(.ini) we can do this by using :

```
app-server-1 ansible_host="123.45.67.8" ansible_user=abcd ansible_password=mypwd
```

but since I want to encrypt the password using ansible vault, I need to put it in 
 a `.yml` file.

A sample example would be highly appreciated as I have tried specifying in **hosts:** section and in **vars:** section, but could not do it when each host has different password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/first_inventory.html#protecting-sensitive-variables-with-ansible-vault)'s example of yaml inventory with generating encrypted password under the group. [Here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/yaml.html)'s example of yaml inventory with host variables:

```
all:
  hosts:
    test1:
      ansible_password:  !vault |
               $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.2;AES256;my_user
               66386134653765386232383236303063623663343437643766386435663632343266393064373933
               3661666132363339303639353538316662616638356631650a316338316663666439383138353032
               63393934343937373637306162366265383461316334383132626462656463363630613832313562
               3837646266663835640a313164343535316666653031353763613037656362613535633538386539
               65656439626166666363323435613131643066353762333232326232323565376635
```